# Why when I undo deleting a folder the contents disappear?

Tags: windows, ssd, storage, nvme, m.2

Lately I have moved some of my documents (using a junction link `mklink /j "link" "target"`) on a faster m.2 drive and I notice that when I delete a folder in there and I later undo it, then go inside that folder and there's nothing there. Which means that I can't find a way to properly undo deleting the folder (and its contents). This only happens to me with this drive. If I do the same on other drives I can undo deleting a foler and all contents will be there. I have only noticed this with this drive that I own for about 2 years now. What is going on here? I'm worried that I might delete something important in the future or that the drive is faulty and I should move all of my contents back to my regular SSD drive. That M.2 drive is noticeably faster and I wouldn't want to do that though. By the way it's a 2.5 year old, 250GB large and it is ~70% full right now if that makes any difference. I have Windows 8.1 x64. Can somebody help? Thank you.

Comment: you could try removing the link, and then recreate it as a hardlink /h or directory /d and see if that works, instead of a junction /j depending on what the target is.

Comment: I'm hesitant to do that; I've been working with junctions successfully for many years now and they have solved so many of my problems. But I'll take that under consideration.

Comment: There is no harm in changing it to a directory junction or hardlink. In worst case, you put it back. Its just a test. If you don't want to remove it, create a new link somewhere else and test there. For all you know, this little trick solves your issues.